# Manually resizing an element doesn't fire a mutation observer in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, resize, mutation-observers

I have a `DIV` with style `resize: both` and then I set a `MutationObserver` that listens for changes in attributes.

```
mutObs = new MutationObserver(function () {
    console.log('Hello');
});

elem = document.getElementById('aDiv');
mutObs.observe(elem, {
    attributes: true
});

elem.style.width = '300px'; //this fires the observer callback as expected
```

I made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2NQQu/2/

In Chrome (I tested Chrome 31) the callback is not fired when you resize the `DIV` with the mouse. In Firefox it works fine.

Is this behavior intentional and/or standard? Is it a bug?

Comment: It's now fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a bug in Chrome, [reported here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=293948). The bug is still open, which means it has not been fixed.

Comment: First reported as a bug Sept 20th, 2013 and it's still an open issue.

Comment: I may have just had this bug again on Chrome v. 102.0.5005.115.