# How to detect DOM element mutations without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, mutation-observers

Let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<div id='content'></div>
```

I'd like to be alerted when height mutations occur on this element. I was hoping the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) class would help in this, but here is my problem with it:

```
document.querySelector('#content').style.height = '100px'
```

It triggers my callback like expected, however normal user interactions won't trigger this, e.g., http://jsfiddle.net/wq4q9/2/

My **question** is, what is the best modern approach for checking if an element's height has changed?

No jQuery please.

Comment: The usual work-around here is to register event handlers for those events which can cause a height change (e.g. window resize, other specific operations in your page, etc...) and then check the height of that object after each one of these other operations occurs.

Comment: Side note: jQuery wouldn't help you here anyway, other than making it really easy to get the height. :-)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [the Chrome bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294828/manually-resizing-an-element-doesnt-fire-a-mutation-observer-in-chrome). Firefox has the same behavior, and there are other ways to resize the element that don't fire mutation observers (and arguably shouldn't).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder put that there mostly to filter out answers with links to jquery plugins

Comment: Humm. FWIW, if you `target` the textarea rather than `#content` in your fiddle, it works in Firefox (in reference to the proposed dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294828/manually-resizing-an-element-doesnt-fire-a-mutation-observer-in-chrome). Your current fiddle is sort-of comparing apples and oranges, as you're asking us to manually resize the textarea, but programatically resize `#content`. If you programatically resize `textarea` instead, the MutationObserver won't fire (http://jsfiddle.net/wq4q9/4/).

Comment: @Matt that's interesting about firefox. Also your fiddle probably showcases the problem better

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything you can do other than poll. (Another way your observer wouldn't be triggered would be if you changed a CSS rule that applied to the element, changed its parent's size and its size was dependent on that, added a new style sheet that affected it...)

Comment: Example of changing parent's size not firing a mutation observer: http://jsfiddle.net/wq4q9/3/

Comment: Thanks T.J -- I'll probably end up polling :)

Comment: T.J: Why should we be expecting the changing of the parent's height to trigger the `MutationObserver`? The element the observer is attached to still isn't being *affected* is it?

Comment: @Matt: It is if (as I said somewhat in passing above) its size was dependent on its parent's size. In the fiddle I did that with `height: 100%`. Changing the parent's height changes the target's height, but doesn't fire a mutation observer callback.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Ahh, I'm with you... because `#content` has `height: 100%`. I should probably have noticed the massive blue box getting bigger when clicking the button, but instead I needed it spelling out for me :P.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably *have* to go along with [T.J. Crowders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) recommendation to poll, however your code example isn't working for other reasons (it seems):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265034%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)* for `childList` says that it is used to monitor additions and removals of the target node's child elements.

<sup>* This is the first and only time I'll reference MSDN as opposed to MDN, because the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) documentation for this is crap</sup>.

---

The record you should be observing is *subtree*:

> Set to true to also monitor changes to all the target node's descendants

---

If you do that, then [the code **works** in Firefox](http://jsfiddle.net/wq4q9/5/).

```
var target = document.querySelector('#content');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  console.log(mutations);   
});

var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true, characterData: true };
observer.observe(target, config);

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',function(){
    target.style.height = '200px';
});
```

*However*, it still doesn't work in Chrome; likely because of the [Chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=293948) reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294828/manually-resizing-an-element-doesnt-fire-a-mutation-observer-in-chrome).