# Is there an event-driven means of responding to a DOM element resizing?

Tags: javascript

I would like to be notified when a DOM element changes its dimensions. I am only targeting the latest version of Chrome. Is this possible yet?

I found:

- [Manually resizing an element doesn't fire a mutation observer in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294828/manually-resizing-an-element-doesnt-fire-a-mutation-observer-in-chrome) which is related, but references making an element resizable.
- https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries This appears to bind to scroll event handlers and record last known size information and then when scroll changes it checks to see if a resize actually happens. I'm wondering if this is the **only** way to do this currently, or if it's just to support non-modern browsers?

Here's a sample of what I'd like to be able to respond to. This snippet does **not** print to the console, but I'd like it to since the child's width grows once the parent's width is modified.

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
  console.log('I fired');
});

var child = document.getElementById('child')
observer.observe(child, {
  attributes: true
});

var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
parent.style.width = '400px';
```

```css
#child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
#parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <div id='child'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19418479/451969

Comment: Right. I mentioned the library referenced there in my post and am looking for more information - if any exists.

Comment: Just aside, real non-modern browsers fire `onresize` on any HTML element, what would be more modern than that ; )

Comment: :p Yeah yeah, the one time I'm wishing I was only targeting IE!

Comment: Since you are only targeting the latest Chrome, this will be a really elegant solution **after** it has been approved/implemented: http://xml3d.org/xml3d/specification/styleobserver/

Comment: Ahhh okay, yep. That looks like what I'm after. Guess it's back to waiting for now. :)